# How to open a pdf from my flatlist in react-native?

Tags: react-native, pdf

Im trying to pick a file (pdf-file) from a module called **react-native-file-picker**. This works ok, and gaves me name, type, path and uri.

After this, i display the name of the document that i picked in a flatlist.

Now, what i want is to "**onPress**" of the item in the flatlist, open the document with some pdf viewer or something like that.

I've already tried to use other modules like **react-native-view-pdf** and **react-native-pdf** and **react-native-pdf-view** but i cant access the state of my uri with either of them.

The last one that i used it was **react-native-file-viewer** and doesn't work very well because it doesn't open the item on press.

This is my actual code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Button, TextInput, 
Dimensions, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
import FilePickerManager from 'react-native-file-picker';
import FileViewer from 'react-native-file-viewer';

global.myfunction = function myfunction() {
FilePickerManager.showFilePicker(null, (response) => {
console.log('Response = ', response);

if (response.didCancel) {
  console.log('User cancelled file picker');
}
else if (response.error) {
  console.log('FilePickerManager Error: ', response.error);
}
else {
  this.storeItem(response)
}
});
};


export default class Docs extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
return {
  title: 'Docs',
  header: null

}
};

state = {
arr: [],
local: '',
password: '',
obj: null,
count: 1,
image: {},
b64: '',
isModalVisible: false,
pdfuri: null,

};

pdf = () => {

FilePickerManager.showFilePicker(null, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled file picker');
  }
  else if (response.error) {
    console.log('FilePickerManager Error: ', response.error);
  }
  else {
    this.storeItem(response)
    this.setState({
      pdfuri: response.path
    });
  }
});



}
toggleModal = (item) => {
this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible, obj: item });
};

 storeItem(item) {
 try {
  //we want to wait for the Promise returned by AsyncStorage.setItem()
  //to be resolved to the actual value before returning the value~
  console.log(item)
  var joined = this.state.arr.concat(item);
  console.log('files   ', joined)

  this.setState({ arr: joined })

  AsyncStorage.setItem('files', JSON.stringify(joined));
  console.log(this.state.arr)

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
}

componentDidMount() {
//Here is the Trick
const { navigation } = this.props;

 }

componentWillMount() {
AsyncStorage.getItem('files').then(array => {
  item = JSON.parse(array)

  item ? this.setState({ arr: item }) : null;
  console.log(this.state.arr)


  })
 }

verpdf() {
const path = 
"content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/4183"
FileViewer.open(path, { showOpenWithDialog: true })
    .then(() => {
      // success
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // error
    });
 }


render() {

return (
  <View style={[styles.container, { marginTop: 20 }]}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.arr}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <TouchableOpacity onPress= 
  {this.verpdf(item)} style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 10, alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>{item.fileName}</Text></TouchableOpacity>}
    />

    <Button title='ok' onPress={this.pdf}></Button>
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

How should i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the event handler from

```
 onPress= 
  {this.verpdf(item)}

to

 onPress= 
  {()=>this.verpdf(item)}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! One more question. On const path = 
"content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/4183 how to i put the path to get my path from every item in flatlist?

Comment: you can try to change signatrure  of  verpdf()  to verpdf(item) {

Answer (score 0):

Like @Oleg said, to open a certain item i needed to change the event handler to a arrow function.

```
onPress = {this.verpdf(item)}
```

to

```
onPress= {()=>this.verpdf(item)}
```

After that i wanted to open a certain item from my flatlist which i did:

```
verpdf(item) {
const path = item.path
FileViewer.open(path, { showOpenWithDialog: true })
.then(() => {
  // success
})
.catch(error => {
  // error
});
}
```